# Windows 7 Jump List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7, jump-list

I think that is what this is called:

[image]

I want to be able to add stuff like that to my program. Such as an open button and other buttons that would **execute a method within the app**. This is in C#, by the way.

I DID look into the Windows 7 API Code Pack, but it.. doesn't work the way I want. It won't let me execute a method inside my app like I want. It just lets you open other apps.

Is something like this possible?

Comment: Hi Eaton, please add some ocde, so we can actually help you. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I never really came up with any code for it since the W7 Code Pack didn't have the functionality I require.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think its you who doesnt understand how JumpLists work.
"It just lets you open other apps" Is exactly what it does, nothing else. Thats Windows 7 feature, not API Code Pack limitation. Key point to this is fact, that your application is not running, so WHERE it should execute your method?
Correct implementation would be to make your JumpList run your application with correct parameters and then inside your application Main method invoke different methods depending on those parameters.
Dont forget, even window applications have input parameters, just like console apps.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at Outlook and Messenger, they invoke other commands within the app, so you know it is possible. But as @Euphoric says, the architecture of jumplists is really simple - choosing a destination (eg a file name or URL) results in Windows launching another instance of the app and passing that destination as a command line argument. Choosing a task results in Windows launching that task, which needs to be some other exe.

How to resolve this seeming paradox? The other exe is a helper exe that communicates with the main app. Examples of this are in short supply but I am working on a demo for an early November talk, and will blog it when I have it done. Perhaps this architectural pointer will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Assign URLs to the jump list items and use an HTTP listener to invoke methods upon your application. Like this [URL mapping with C# HttpListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017564/url-mapping-with-c-sharp-httplistener)

Additionally, you can go the awekward route and use a shared mutex to make your application single instance only and forward command line arguments across a named pipe. But the http listener is nicer ;)