# URL mapping with C# HttpListener

Tags: c#, http, url-mapping

In the code below I am waiting for any call to the 8080 port.

```cs
public static void Main()
{
    HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
    listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
    
    listener.Start();
    
    while(isRunning)
    {
        HttpListenerContext ctx = listener.GetContext();
        new Thread(new Worker(ctx).ProcessRequest).Start();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to map specific URL patterns to different behavior? I want achieve a REST-style server i.e. a call to `localhost:8080/person/1` will launch `getPersonHandler(int)`

```cs
[Mapping("*:8080/person/$id")]
public void getPersonHandler(int id)
{
   // ...
}
```

The `Mapping` syntax is just my wishful analogy to JAX-RS libraries that I know. I would like to do the same in C# (desktop C#, not asp).

Comment: Do you really need to reinvent the wheel?  Web API in ASP.NET MVC 4 can do this.

Comment: I need a standalone application.

Comment: FYI ASP.NET Web API can be self-hosted (no IIS)

Comment: If ASP.NET Web API can self-host inside an executable I'd like to see that! (Not saying it can't, just that I don't know that it can).

Comment: Use OWIN to self-host: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/use-owin-to-self-host-web-api

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can get a similar effect without attributes

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
    HttpListenerContext ctx = listener.GetContext();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) =>
    {
        string methodName = ctx.Request.Url.Segments[1].Replace("/", "");
        string[] strParams = ctx.Request.Url
                                .Segments
                                .Skip(2)
                                .Select(s=>s.Replace("/",""))
                                .ToArray();


        var method = this.GetType().GetMethod(methodName);
        object[] @params = method.GetParameters()
                            .Select((p, i) => Convert.ChangeType(strParams[i], p.ParameterType))
                            .ToArray();

        object ret = method.Invoke(this, @params);
        string retstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ret);
    });
```

Usage would be:

```
http://localhost:8080/getPersonHandler/333
```

if you really want to use Attributes then

```
HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
listener.Prefixes.Add("http://*:8080/");
listener.Start();
while (true)
{
    HttpListenerContext ctx = listener.GetContext();
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((_) =>
    {
        string methodName = ctx.Request.Url.Segments[1].Replace("/", "");
        string[] strParams = ctx.Request.Url
                                .Segments
                                .Skip(2)
                                .Select(s=>s.Replace("/",""))
                                .ToArray();

        var method = this.GetType()
                            .GetMethods()
                            .Where(mi => mi.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(attr => attr is Mapping && ((Mapping)attr).Map == methodName))
                            .First();

        object[] @params = method.GetParameters()
                            .Select((p, i) => Convert.ChangeType(strParams[i], p.ParameterType))
                            .ToArray();

        object ret = method.Invoke(this, @params);
        string retstr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ret);
    });
}
```

Then you can use as `http://localhost:8080/Person/333` and your definitions would be

```
class Mapping : Attribute
{
    public string Map;
    public Mapping(string s)
    {
        Map = s;
    }
}

[Mapping("Person")]
public void getPersonHandler(int id)
{
    Console.WriteLine("<<<<" + id);
}
```

Comment: what is this @param kind of variable name?

Comment: since `params` is reserved word in c# I used `@params`

Comment: I didnt know you can use `@` in variable names, thanks. I like this answer. Thank you very much.

Comment: One last thing: can you also filter by request type (GET,PUT ...) ?

Comment: @elmes `ctx.Request.HttpMethod`

Answer (score 10):

If you are working in .NET 4.0 or higher and looking for a pre-existing REST server solution that you can plug into (which it sounds like you are), you might want to check out [Grapevine](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine).  You can get it using NuGet, and the [project wiki](https://github.com/sukona/Grapevine/wiki) has lots of sample code. Plus, it is open source, so if you just wanted to see how it can be accomplished, you can see all the source code there.

You can filter requests by path info (using regular expressions) and request methods (GET, POST, etc.).

I am the project author, and I had a similar need as the one you described.  Using resources I found here and elsewhere, I built Grapevine so that I would have a solution in my back pocket whenever I needed it again ([DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)).

Comment: Nice project - I needed to put a REST API into a command line app, and Grapevine was much cleaner than the stock HttpListener class in C#.