# Retrieve HTTP POST request containing XML

Tags: c#, xml, http, iis, post

I need to setup a web page that listens for XML document via an HTTP POST. I don't need to POST out, I need to receive that POST. What object does this? Should I use an HTTP handler, web service, webRequest, Stream or something else? I need to use a IIS Server and prefer C#.

**I've Tried...**

1. I dont think I can use WebRequest since I'm not sending a request, just waiting for them.
2. "HttpRequest.InputStream" but I'm not sure how to use it or where to put it. Do i need to use it with a web service or a asp.net application? I put it in
   http://forums.asp.net/t/1371873.aspx/1
3. I've tried a simple web service http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412178.aspx - But when i try to visit "http://localhost:8000/EchoWithGet?s=Hello, world!", i get a "webpage cannot be found error"

If anyone has any helpful code or links that would be great!

EDIT:
I am trying to receive notifications from another program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017564/url-mapping-with-c-sharp-httplistener

Comment: Thanks, but I was trying to stay away from the network layer.

Comment: @numbe, It is not TcpListener, it's HttpListener so nothing to do with NW layer, but of course, your code your choise.

Comment: oh okay, thanks ill try it out. the handler method isn't working for me

Comment: @nubme, did you sort out this problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could write an ASP.NET application that you will host in IIS in which you could either have an .ASPX page or a generic [.ASHX handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986.aspx) (depending on how you want the result to be formatted - do you want to return HTML or some other type) and then read the `Request.InputStream` which will contain the body of the request that comes from the client.

Here's an example of how you could write a generic handler (`MyHandler.ashx`):

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var stream = context.Request.InputStream;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

        ... do something with the XML

        // We only set the HTTP status code to 202 indicating to the
        // client that the request has been accepted for processing
        // but we leave an empty response body
        context.Response.StatusCode = 202;
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont need to return anything, I'm just receiving notifications from another program.

I tried Request.InputStream, and put a breakpoints in the code. It doesn't seem to catch any notifications. My code is very similar to the link above for try #2. I put it in Page_load. Does a POST Request trigger Page_load each time?

Comment: HTTP is a request/response based protocol. So you must always return something. You could return a 200 status code with an empty body indicating to the client the success of the operation.

Comment: I see, I'll try out the code and let you know. Thanks for the help! =]

Comment: So i got your code to work i think... I'm using wfetch to sent GET & POST requests. The code is able to see the GET request, but nothing happens when i send POST. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: nm you gotta ping the exact page, can't just do localhost

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where to call or use the handler. This is what i have so far...

Default.aspx

```
<%@Page Inherits="WebApplication1._Default"%>
<%@OutputCache Duration="10" Location="Server" varybyparam="none"%>
<script language="C#" runat="server">
  void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs args) {

  }     
}
</script>
<html>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
namespace WebApplication1  
{
  public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext contex = Context;
        MyHandler temp = new MyHandler();
        temp.ProcessRequest(context);
    }
  }

    public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
       public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
       {
         var stream = context.Request.InputStream;
         byte[] buffer = new byte[stream.Length];
         stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
         string xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);

         ... do something with the XML

        // We only set the HTTP status code to 202 indicating to the
        // client that the request has been accepted for processing
        // but we leave an empty response body
        context.Response.StatusCode = 202;
       }

      public bool IsReusable
      {
        get
        {
          return false;
        }
      }
   }
}
```