# C# communication with browser using JavaScript

Tags: c#, javascript, serial-port, tcplistener

How to pass messages to C# application from JavaScript, I'm able to do this with PHP and tcpListner in c#(but using PHP need server to host), i need localhost communicate c# application with browser(using javaScript or any other possible way), browser need to pass messages to application running on same matchine

can you suggest appropriate method for this with sample

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017564/url-mapping-with-c-sharp-httplistener

Comment: no i need browser to pass messages to c# application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in the following way.

**step 1** : you have to create a Listener. **TcpListener** class or **HttpListener**   in .net can be used to develop the listener. This code shows how to implement a TCP listener.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

//Author : Kanishka 
namespace ServerSocketApp
{
class Server
{
 private TcpListener tcpListn = null;
 private Thread listenThread = null;
 private bool isServerListening = false;

 public Server()
 {
  tcpListn = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any,8090);
  listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(listeningToclients));
  this.isServerListening = true;
  listenThread.Start();
 }

 //listener
 private void listeningToclients()
 {
  tcpListn.Start();
  Console.WriteLine("Server started!");
  Console.WriteLine("Waiting for clients...");
  while (this.isServerListening)
  {
   TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListn.AcceptTcpClient();
   Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(handleClient));
   clientThread.Start(tcpClient);
  }

 }

 //client handler
 private void handleClient(object clientObj)
 {
  TcpClient client = (TcpClient)clientObj;
  Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");

  NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
  ASCIIEncoding asciiEnco = new ASCIIEncoding();

  //read data from client
  byte[] byteBuffIn = new byte[client.ReceiveBufferSize];
  int length = stream.Read(byteBuffIn, 0, client.ReceiveBufferSize);
  StringBuilder clientMessage = new StringBuilder("");
  clientMessage.Append(asciiEnco.GetString(byteBuffIn));

  //write data to client
  //byte[] byteBuffOut = asciiEnco.GetBytes("Hello client! \n"+"You said : " + clientMessage.ToString() +"\n Your ID  : " + new Random().Next());
  //stream.Write(byteBuffOut, 0, byteBuffOut.Length);
  //writing data to the client is not required in this case

  stream.Flush();
  stream.Close();
  client.Close(); //close the client
 }

 public void stopServer()
 {
  this.isServerListening = false;
  Console.WriteLine("Server stoped!");
 }

}
}
```

**Step 2** : you can pass parameters to the created server as a GET request. You can use either JavaScript or HTML Forms to pass parameters. JavaScript libraries like jQuery and Dojo will make it easier to make ajax requests.

```
http://localhost:8090?id=1133
```

You have to modify the above code to retrieve the parameters send as a GET request.
I recommend to use **HttpListener** instead of **TcpListener**

Once you have done with the listening part rest part is just processing the retrieved parameters from the request.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `HttpListener` class, or create a self-hosted ASP.Net Web API project.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a something like Comet, [check this example using Comet](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27699/Scalable-COMET-Combined-with-ASP-NET-Part-2)