# Using TCP listener or HTTP listener Along with IIS

Tags: javascript, c#, iis, tcp

I would like to implement a solution where I can pass data from my web page to a C# Application running on the same client PC that the browser is running on. After some research I found that using a TCP Listener or HTTP Listener, one can implement such a system - By making ajax requests/posts and then letting the listener catch these requests, then one can access the data in the request.

I then set out to write a small test application and hooray, it works! I used the code I found [here(see answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299389/c-sharp-communication-with-browser-using-javascript) to implement a simple TCP listener, then opened my browser and navigated to `http://localhost:8090/` and like I should, I saw the data that the listener responded with. This is great and all but now I have the problem that this listener needs to work along side my IIS server (or actually any service that will be hosting my wep app).

So I created a basic html page and added it as a site on IIS and tested it in the broweser to see if it works, so I simply navigated to `http://localhost:8081/index.html` and my test page showed up. That's good - Then I changed the port that the listener is listening to from `8090` to `8081`, which is the port that IIS is using to host my site, and when I tried to start my listener with the new port I got the execption "`An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`". Is IIS causing this problem, or will what I'm trying to do not work in any case because I'm using it in the wrong context.

Another thing I would like to do is rather use a HTTP Listener, but the only HTTP Listener examples I can find is individuals using it to create simple HTTP servers that actually serves the html and other resources to the browser [(e.g. here)](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=784). All I want is a HTTP Listener implementation of the code mentioned previously in the thread I linked.

**In Summary**: Like I mentioned in my introduction `...implement a solution where I can pass data from my web page to a C# Application...`, my end goal is to achieve communication to my C# app from my web page, doesn't matter if I use a HTTP or TCP Listener.

Comment: Only one application can listen on any given port at a time, i.e. the HTTP server and TCP servers need to be listening on distinct and separate ports, hence the error. You would send/receive data using normal AJAX on the client side, to http://localhost:8090/ - they don't need to be on the same port to communicate, just the same domain

Comment: As @JonathanBrooks mentioned the error is about port usage. Also if I understood you correctly you have a working example with a listener. So, you know how to pass variable to c#.

Answer (score 0):

I found by solution [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/599978/An-HttpListener-Server-for-Handling-AJAX-POST-Requ). By using a HTTP Listener and waiting for and handling ajax posts made to a specific url and port.