# IIS or selfhost for this service?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, iis-7, self-hosting

**Hi,**

I have a complexed layered WCF service, it is really containing 4 different services where 3 is using regular BasicHTTPBinding and the last one netTCPBinding.

Here is som facs :

1. Loading data on startup
2. Never recycle or restart (running 24/7)
3. 5000 windows clients
4. Callbacks to keep clients up to date
5. Caching data for faster response
6. Custom login with both userPassword and active directory
7. Message inspectors
8. Possible to host multiple instances of this service(that contains 4 services) on the same computer
9. Using profobuf for WCF on the TCP service to gain performance
10. No compression of data
11. Active Directory communication
12. Certificates
13. Custom/Regular Performance counters

This service have been hosted in IIS7 for a while but to remove the WAS overhead and gain performance I have now also created a Windows Service to host it in.

But I got a couple of questions :

1. Will WCF be fully functional, for example crashes throttling?
2. How do I handle if the service craches? I need it to restart as fast as possible

Comment: How much WAS overhead did you measure? How much did perf improve after switching to a Windows service?

Comment: You just configure the Service to restart.  See the Recovery tab.

Comment: @usr > I setup 6 clients that sended light requests to the service as fast as possible and the gain over 15 min was 20%. BUT if we use hard numbers we got around 00:00:00.31 per call with IIS and 00:00:00.24 with selfhost. I did not get around to test larger packages but I the diffrence would probably be alot less there.

Comment: @Blam > So you mean if the service is craching I can set the Windows service to restart automatically?

Comment: Take one step further and use HttpListener :)

Comment: @SnowJim like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017564/url-mapping-with-c-sharp-httplistener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Services right click the service and select Properties.  The second is a Recovery tab with lots of options.   There are going to be some hangs the Services doesn't catch to Recover.  But it should sense a crash.