# Pass existing query string parameters to method

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, query-string

I have a controller that looks like this

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("reporting_values")]
public HttpResponseMessage List()
{
   var queryString = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();

// SomeMethod( ** all parameters that exist in the query string ** )

   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

My queryString-variable (key-value pairs) could look something like:
Name - "John Doe"
Age - 31

I would like to pass name and age to SomeMethod *if they exist*. My query string parameters are optional, thus I would like to use the parameters that were actually passed in the query string in SomeMethod.

i.e. url/reporting_values?Name=John
should result in SomeMethod(Name)

url/reporting_values
should result in SomeMethod()

Is there any way to do this? If not, is there any other way to make efficient use of optional query string parameters?

Comment: Maybe you can use reflection. Not exactly answers your question but you may get a hint... http://stackoverflow.com/a/10017974/932418