# C# - How to handle HttpListener requests like Discord.NET commands?

Tags: c#, http, request, listener, discord.net

Does anyone know if it’s possible to handle requests in HttpListener similar to how commands are handled in Discord.NET?

Example:

```
[HttpPost(“SomeUrl”)]
public void SomeMethod()
{
 //code happens here
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: No, the lib does not support that. You would have to make your own implementation.

Comment: Looks like this question brings up the same topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017564/url-mapping-with-c-sharp-httplistener

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL mapping with C# HttpListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017564/url-mapping-with-c-sharp-httplistener)